# Aws lambda calling s3.getObject in node gives Specified key does not exist

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda written in NodeJs which is invoked through an API gateway endpoint.

The lambda receives token in event headers and a parameter in event params.
Using these a dynamic path is built to retrieve the object from s3.

The initial request with the given path to S3 getObject() fails saying "The specified key does not exist." with status code 404.

When requested again with same parameters and token gives success and proceeds.(The key is found on S3 this time.)

```
s3.getObject(authParams, function (err, authData) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return callback(err);
    } 
}
```

authParams consist of Bucket name and Key to the data.
authParams is same for both requests.

This happens when requesting from postman or from SFDC.

The same lambda invoked locally with same parameters works fine.

Cross verified the data is present at that S3 path and the URL or link to that object is also same.

Comment: double-check you data sent from lmabda to S3 API to make sure the value of file-name is ok. "The specified key does not exist." that means there are no given file-name found.  Check `folder_name`, `file_name`

Comment: Yes, I have checked that, and both times the key or the path is same, 
but it only gives me this error on the first request. 
The second request with the same key fetches the object from S3.

Comment: You are trying to get newly file on S3? Maybe it is the delay???

Comment: No, the data is not newly created. It exists as a permanent store.
Calling s3.getObject() from node console with the same key gets the data.

Only the first callout from the code fails responding "The specified key does not exist." Next call works fine.

Comment: "The specified key does not exist" should be accompanied by an XML response body listing the specific key that was requested.  It may be useful to find a way to access that body and see what key the service thinks you are requesting.  It also might be useful to enable logging on your bucket, and then review the logs to see what key was actually requested but not found.  It may also be useful to show more of your code, since a scoping error could explain why it works the second time.